# A question on separable space

Tags: general-topology

Let $f$ be a continous function from a separable space $X$ to a separable space $Y$. Define the Limit set of $f$, denoted by $L(f)$ as follows:
$$L(f)=\{y|\exists x_n\in X, \textrm{s.t. }\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=y, (\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty})'=\phi\}$$
where $(\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty})'$ is the derived set of $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Show that $L(f)$ is closed.

I have the following idea: for all $y\in L(f)$, we should construct a sequence $x_{n,k}$ with each of ${x_{n,k}}|_{k=0}^{\infty}$ has empty derived set, but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_{n,k})=y$$ with subsequence $x_{n_i,k_i}$, such that its derived set is also empty(this restriction makes me lost), and $\lim_{i\to\infty}f(x_{n_i,k_i})=y$. It is obvious that when the dimension is finite, but I have no idea about the infinite dimension case.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: What other topological assumptions do you have on $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @ThomasE. there are no other restrictions

Comment: Alright, thanks. The last sentence about dimensions confused me a little bit. Also while trying to follow the idea you posted, if all you said would be true, how would the closedness of $L(f)$ follow? And why do you want to construct those sequences?

Comment: @ThomasE. I'd like use the definition of closedness to prove the theorem. $y_n\to y$, there exists $x_{n_i,k_i}\to y$. Here $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n,k}=y_n$, I omitted this step before.

Comment: Are you sure $X$ and $Y$ are not metric spaces? Or at least first countable? Or which definition of closedness do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is false without further hypotheses. Let $Y$ be a [Mrówka $\Psi$-space](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/): $Y$ consists of a countable dense set $D$ of isolated points and a closed discrete set $L$ of limit points of $D$. Each point of $L$ is the limit of a sequence of points of $D$, and each infinite sequence of distinct points of $D$ has a subsequence converging to some point of $L$. Finally, $Y$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, so it has a one-point compactification $Y^*$; let $p$ be the point at infinity in $Y^*$. If $\{y_k:k\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq D$, there is a sequence $\langle y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to some $y\in L$; let $K=\{y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{y\}$. Then $K$ is a compact subset of $Y$, so $Y^*\setminus K$ is a nbhd of $p$, and the sequence $\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $p$. Thus, $p$ is not the limit of any sequence of points of $D$.

Let $X$ be a countably infinite discrete space; clearly $X$ and $Y^*$ are both separable, and if $A\subseteq X$, the derived set of $A$ is empty. Let $f:X\to Y^*$ be an injection of $X$ onto $D$. If $y\in L$, there is a sequence $\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $D$ converging to $y$, so $y\in L(f)$, and therefore $L\subseteq L(f)$. The point $p$ is not the limit of any sequence in $D$, so $p\notin L(f)$. However, $p\in\operatorname{cl}L$, so $p\in\operatorname{cl}L(f)\setminus L(f)$, and $L(f)$ is not closed.